# Execute a function when certain conditions are met

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

my django app have a function which is `send_sms`, I also want to have a automatic sms `auto_sms` function. when conditions are met on my data models.

@views.py

```
def send_sms(request):
    z = Rainfall.objects.latest('timestamp')
    numbers = Mobile.objects.all()
    message = ('Test Message')

    account_sid = '**************'
    auth_token = '**************'

    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    for i in numbers:
        client.messages.create(to=i.mobile_number,
                               from_='**************',
                               body=message)


    return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/', 200)


def auto_sms(request):
    responses = Rainfall.objects.filter(
        level='Torrential' or 'Intense',
        timestamp__gt=now() - timedelta(days=1),
        sms_sent=False,
    )
    if responses.count() >= 10:
        send_sms(request)
        responses.update(sms_sent=True)
```

@models.py

```
class Rainfall(models.Model):
    level = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, default='')
    amount = models.FloatField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now I'm testing it, that when `auto_sms` detects multiple(10) 'Torrential or Intense' entries into the database within a day. It must automatically execute `send_sms` but instead its returning an error:

`Cannot resolve keyword 'sms_sent' into field. Choices are: amount, id, level, timestamp`

what am I missing here? please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no field in your `Rainfall` class called `sms_sent` - consider adding the field or altering your query:

```
class Rainfall(models.Model):
    ...
    sms_sent = models.BooleanField(default=False) # add this field

    # override save method:
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if <some conditions are met>:

             # send sms:
             self.send_sms()
             self.sms_sent = True

        super(Rainfall, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Btw, I have another model that records SMS logs, can I use that instead?

Comment: Hello, I have the updated code above. I removed the `sent_sms`. it actually works but only on manual execution. my problem now is how to make it automatic. haha

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE`

Hello,

My rainfall model looks like this actually. sorry, I will make it detailed now.

@models.py

```
class Rainfall(models.Model):
    level = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, default='')
    amount = models.FloatField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def update_level(self):
        if 0.1 <= self.amount < 2.5:
            return 'Light'
        elif 2.5 <= self.amount < 7.5:
            return 'Moderate'
        elif 7.5 < self.amount < 15:
            return 'Heavy'
        elif 15 <= self.amount < 30:
            return 'Intense'
        elif 30 <= self.amount < 50:
            return 'Torrential'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.level:
            self.level = self.update_level()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Sms(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and my views.py look like this.

```
def send_sms(request):
    z = Rainfall.objects.latest('timestamp')
    numbers = Mobile.objects.all()
    message = (f'Test ({z.timestamp})')

    account_sid = '*******'
    auth_token = '********'

    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    for i in numbers:
        client.messages.create(to=i.mobile_number,
                               from_='********',
                               body=message)

    record = Sms.objects.create(description=f'{message}')
    record.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/api/', 200)



def auto_sms(request):
    responses = Rainfall.objects.filter(
        level='Torrential' or 'Intense',
        timestamp__gt=now() - timedelta(days=1),
    )
    if responses.count() >= 5:
        send_sms(request)

    return HttpResponse(200)
```

Now I can't add another field on my rainfall, can I use the SMS model instead? for the automation of `auto_sms`? Thanks

Comment: See my updated answer. You have a few options, post save signals, overriding the save method, etc. In my answer I provided an overridden save method with some sudo code.

Comment: Hello, Thanks! I added another comment for the latest code. can you please check it? thanks! sorry for the messy explanation before.